# Looking for openFDA datasets which gives JSON data

Tags: data-request, data.gov, openfda, json

I am looking for openFDA datasets for my current academic project. The project describes that a user enters medicine name and the result has to show me the information about the adverse events based on the medicine name. To do this kind of thing I must have a dataset. I did a lot of research but i am not able to get it. Please help me guys.

Comment: It sounds like you already know that openFDA is one source of the data you're looking for.. what problems are you having accessing it?

Comment: It's not about accessing. It's all about how can we get the dataset? We have gone through the website. We know what we have to search. But we don't have a resource(dataset) to search in for. Thank you for your immediate response. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They way openFDA stands, it is an API which returns JSON for a search. I too have asked for bulk downloads.

The information you seem to be looking for is available by modifying the following API call:

`https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:advil&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact&limit=1000`

If you are looking to do this with an offline data set (aka not need to query the API each time), you have a few options:

- Cache the results for a week or two
- Go through a list of all drugs and download the results and store that in a database of your own
- Completely bypass openFDA API and go to the source data at http://www.fda.gov/Drugs/GuidanceComplianceRegulatoryInformation/Surveillance/AdverseDrugEffects/ucm082193.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate it. Is it possible to know the exact fields. Because we also need to analyze the dataset based on gender and then by age. So if at all we got to the know the fields. Then I can work on it. Sorry for asking you many questions.

Comment: Yes, you can get all fields for all the AE event reports by removing the `&count=..` from the URL (`https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:advil&limit=1000`) but you will then have to calculate all the counts yourself. You could also do a count for a certain age range in an API call. It sounds like you need to think through your infrastructure needs and if you want to do a lot of API calls to openFDA or somehow archive/cache all the data yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the Adverse Event API reference page. It is possible to filter based on medication name, patient age, gender and many other fields:

https://open.fda.gov/drug/event/reference/#patient